# Stop float right dropping to next line (Float Drop)

Tags: css, css-float

I have the following code at http://jsfiddle.net/ssCqe/, I am trying to get the text "icon" not to drop to the next line.

**Updated**

Seems it doesn't work in firefox 10.0.1

Please can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't appear to be 'dropping' in Chromium 18. What browser are you using?

Comment: @rene Im usuing Firefox 10.0.1

Comment: Confirmed in Firefox 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove `white-space: nowrap;` from `UL.jqueryFileTree LI` it works on FF, IE9 and Chrome

Check it on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/wW9tN/1/)

Comment: Thanks very much, just the job.